# Alluxio Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, cloudera-cdh, alluxio

I am able to run wordcount on alluxio with an example jar provided by cloudera, using:

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-examples.jar wordcount -libjars /home/nn1/alluxio-1.2.0/core/client/target/alluxio-core-client-1.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar alluxio://nn1:19998/wordcount alluxio://nn1:19998/wc1
```

and it's a success.

But I can't run it when I use the jar created with the ATTACHED CODE, This is also a sample wordcount example
[code](http://pastebin.com/8pMftt02)

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop jar /home/nn1/HadoopWordCount-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar edu.am.bigdata.C45TreeModel.C45DecisionDriver -libjars /home/nn1/alluxio-1.2.0/core/client/target/alluxio-core-client-1.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar alluxio://10.30.60.45:19998/abdf alluxio://10.30.60.45:19998/outabdf
```

Above code is build using maven
Pom.xml file contains

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.4.5</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0-cdh5.4.5</version>
     </dependency>
```

Could you please help me in running my wordcount program in alluxio cluster. Hope no extra configurations are added into pom file for running the same.

I am getting the following error after running my jar :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS:
>   alluxio://10.30.60.45:19998/outabdf, expected: hdfs://10.30.60.45:8020
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:657)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getPathName(DistributedFileSystem.java:194)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.access$000(DistributedFileSystem.java:106)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$19.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1215)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$19.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1211)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1211)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1412)
>       at edu.WordCount.run(WordCount.java:47)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>       at edu.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:23)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the call to

`FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);`

on line 101. The `FileSystem` created by `FileSystem.get(conf)` will only support paths with the scheme defined by Hadoop's `fs.defaultFS` property. To fix the error, change that line to

`FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create("alluxio://nn1:19998/", conf)`

By passing a `URI`, you override `fs.defaultFS`, enabling the created `FileSystem` to support paths using the `alluxio://` scheme.

You could also fix the error by modifying `fs.defaultFS` in your `core-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>alluxio://nn1:19998/</value>
</property>
```

However, this could impact other systems that share the `core-site.xml` file, so I recommend the first approach of passing an `alluxio://` URI to `FileSystem.get()`